# Mouse scroll dropdown list of ComboBox in Excel 2016 64-bit

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a ComboBox dropdown list that has 150+ lines. I was wondering if there's a way to control the scrolling with the mouse wheel over the lines so you don't need to use the bar on the right.

Comment: instead of scrolling, can't you type the first letter of the word?

Comment: In many cases there lines that have several words, each with the same first word, so unfortunately this is not a very good option. :(

Comment: I don't think there is an answer to this question, Excel is built a specific way. But i'm most likely wrong, Good luck though!